# Nesting stacks in react-navigation 5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm trying to migrate my current codebase (react-navigation 4) to work with react-navigation 5.

My code before migrating:

`AppNavigator.js`

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import { AuthLoading } from "../screens/auth";
import AuthStack from "./stacks/AuthStack";
import AppStack from "./stacks/AppStack";

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      App: AppStack,
    },
    { initialRouteName: "AuthLoading" }
  )
);
```

Example for `AuthStack.js`

```
import { Auth, Registration, Login, VerifyAuth } from "../../screens/auth";

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Auth: {
      screen: Auth,
    },
    Registration: {
      screen: Registration,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
    }
  },
  { initialRouteName: "Auth" }
);

export default AuthStack;
```

The `AuthLoading.js` function who is responsible for deciding which stack to render looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StatusBar, View } from "react-native";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";
import TokensHandler from "../../api/TokensHandler";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { isUserExistsByToken, setIsUserExists } from "../../actions/authAction";

const AuthLoading = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isUserExists = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isUserExists);

  const [allowNavigate, setAllowNavigate] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const token = await TokensHandler.getTokenFromDevice();

    if (token === null) {
      dispatch(setIsUserExists(false));
      setAllowNavigate(true);
    } else
      dispatch(isUserExistsByToken(token)).then(() => setAllowNavigate(true));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (allowNavigate || isUserExists != null)
      navigation.navigate(isUserExists ? "App" : "Auth");
  }, [allowNavigate, isUserExists]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default AuthLoading;
```

I've read the docs, but unfortunately I couldn't find anywhere how to refactor a boilerplate of my code to work with react-navigation 5.

What I've tried:

`AuthStack.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { Auth, Registration, Login, VerifyAuth } from "../../screens/auth";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Auth">
      <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={Auth} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={Registration} />

      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AuthStack;
```

I don't know how to even write `AppNavigator.js`, What I've tried:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { AuthLoading } from "../screens/auth";
import AuthStack from "./stacks/AuthStack";
import AppStack from "./stacks/AppStack";

const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isLoggedIn);
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

<Stack.Navigator>{isLoggedIn ? <AuthStack /> : <AppStack />}</Stack.Navigator>;
```

Would apperciate any sort of help,

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to switch between two stacks based on isLoggedIn ?

Comment: Yeah something like that, I just want it to be as identical as possible to the prev version, grouping together some stacks and navigate between those stacks inside screens.

Answer (score 2):

The similar code to the AppNavigator you have on top would be like below

```
//Inside the functional component
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    {isLoggedIn ? <AuthStack /> : <AppStack />}
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Here one stack would be rendered at a given time, and once you update the isLogged value in redux the other stack would be rendered.

To compare it with the code you have in v4 :
The NavigationContainer replaces the createAppContainer and the conditional rendering of the stack replaces the switch navigator.

Comment: To add to this answer. You can read more about it here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#switch-navigator in the documentation.

Comment: This looks like something I'm looking for, but how can I also add  something like initialRouteName: "AuthLoading" ? That's the first component responsible for navigating between the AppStack and AuthStack, it gets a token from the device and validates it with a server, So I want to load it first.

Comment: whats the condition for it to be shown ? lets say something like loading you can wrap it in a separate stack, otherwise you will have an unwanted stack navigator as a wrapper for all these stacks

Comment: There's no condition for it to be shown, That's the first component we are looking for because it tells us which stack to render, I'll edit my question and add it's source code.

Comment: You wont be able to do that in this approach as this switches the stacks or screens based on condition, so better if you can have a state value for it and switch based on that

Comment: You can see the reference for migration here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/ even there its specified to use condition

Comment: Then what do you guys think, that will be better approach to handle this problem?

Comment: dispatch(setIsUserExists(false)); along with this dispatch maintain a state value called isloading in redux level and have the loading true and change it to false in the setisuerexist dispatch based on isLoading and isLoggedIn  switch the stacks, here you dont have to navigate like the switch navigator, the rendering takes care of that based on the conditions

Comment: Is this the correct approach? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62970998/13208120

Comment: Although I still find it hard to render a loading indicator and when the dispatch ends to navigate to the desired stack. Would you mind taking a look at my other post?

Comment: Anyway we can have a chat ?

Comment: you've said 'component does not re-renders when isUserExists' thats the same code in your V4, was it working before ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to move to chat, If you can open one I'll be glad. Also, Yes, according to how the old AuthLoading was written, it did work at the previous version

Comment: if you console.log isUserExists somewhere do you get the new value ?